# Compairing two strings in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a sequence of 20 numbers from 0 to 2, I want to compare this string with other sequences saved in my database, the problem is that the lenght of the strings saved on the database fluctuates.Also the comparison needs to be done from the end to the start.
Example of what I want:

**20 digits string:**

'1,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,2,1'

**couple of strings saved in the database:**

**1 -** '1,1,2,1'

**2 -** '2,1,2,2,2,2'

**3 -** '2,1'

**4 -** '1,1,2,1,2,1'

In this case the query would return the **1** and **3** only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table mytable ( s varchar(60) );

insert into mytable values
('1,1,2,1'),
('2,1,2,2,2,2'),
('2,1'),
('1,1,2,1,2,1');


set @x = '1,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,2,1';

select s from mytable
where right(@x, length(s)) = s;
```

Output:

| s |
| --- |
| 1,1,2,1 |
| 2,1 |

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r5m2hPbnmUu5VQfYvMVtir/0

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `LIKE` trick here.  For example, to check for the first string `1,1,2,1`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ',1,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,' LIKE '%,1,1,2,1,%';
```

Comment: note that they have to match at the end, and that they are always one digit numbers so no extra comma needed:  `'1,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,2,1' LIKE CONCAT('%',tablevalue)`